# Adding comma after each two digits in String.Format

Tags: c#, string, formatting, string-formatting

I was trying to format a number `173910234.23` to something like `17,39,10,234.23`. Here only the first thousand separator is after three digits. But after that all separators (`,`) are after two digits. I have tried the following -

```
double d = 173910234.23;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,##,##,###.00}", d));
```

but it gives output with comma after every three digits, `173,910,234.23`

How can I achieve the format `17,39,10,234.23` using `string.Format`?

Comment: Are you sure? you need `17,39,10,234.23` or `1,73,91,02,34.23`

Comment: I need `17,39,10,234.23`. I am sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Number groups are defined by `NumberGroupSizes` property of `NumberFormatInfo`. So modify it accordingly and just use `N` format specifier.

```
double d = 173910234.23;
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-us", true)
{
    NumberFormat =
    {
        NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 }
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N", culture));
```

This outputs

```
17,39,10,234.23
```

---

Thanks @Rawling and @Hamlet, for shedding light on this. Now OP gets expected output and me too learned something..

Comment: Hey, I've never hear of [`NumberGroupSizes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before now, but if you make it `new int[] { 3, 2 }` it should do *exactly* what OP wants.

Comment: After setting `NumberGroupSizes` you can just use standard number format as `d.ToString("N", culture)`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yup, you're right I just copied from question. Didn't realized whether it is useful or not.

Comment: Community making this answer more and more good.. Thank you all.. :)

Comment: I didn't know about `NumberGroupSizes`. But I knew that there has to be something like this :).

Comment: Just FYI, the same `culture` can also be used to parse string `"17,39,10,234.23"` to double. `Double.Parse("17,39,10,234.23", culture)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = null;    
string num = Number.ToString();
for(int i = 0; i < num.Length; ++i)
 {
        switch(i)
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
            output += ",".ToString() + num[i].ToString(); 
        break;
        default:
            output += num[i].ToString(); 
        break:
 }
```

If you want to use a different number, replace the numbers with the positions of the numbers where you want to insert the comma before (remember the first character of a string has the position of **0**)